# Receive Google user's id token in Google App Script from backend server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-signin

I am trying to create a backend service that helps track change in user's google sheet timely and send notificatioin.

From the [Google Apps Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization), I can access the user's active sheet and cell, which helps my service recognize which content in the google sheet to track.

From the [Google Sign-In Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth), I can access the user's google sheet in order to retrieve the sheet's content and therefore know the changes to notify.

However I am not sure how to retrieve the user's id token, since it is not recommended to directly send the user's id to backend so as to prevent malicious requests to my server using fake user id.

One way I can think of is to integrate google sign-in to the Google App script, but I don't think it will be optimal?